# How to include a user component to LWUIT 1.5 GUI Builder?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, gui-builder

I'd like to have any `Form` managed through the `StateMachine` generated from LWUIT's 1.5 GUI Builder but I have my component which extends `Components` and also my own `Layouts`. How to add them to gui builder as custom `Component`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways. The first override:

```
   protected Component createComponentInstance(String componentType, Class cls)
```

Which allows you to replace all components of a given type (E.g. make your own subclass for all the forms).

The second option is to add them at runtime.

We used to allow used components using the pickMIDlet functionality but that's a bit problematic since a user class might not be compilable while editing a res file.

Answer (score 1):

You must create them in the GUI builder, you can't export your own `Component`from code to the GUI Builder. Build them in the Gui Builder and if this component is a `Container` you can create instance of this usign `StateMachine.createContainer(resource, "nameContainer");`. To manage the `Forms`through the `StateMachine`, you can use `StatMachine.showForm("nameForm");` to show a `Form` and `StateMachine.back()` to go back in the navigation.

Comment: Unfortunately... hopefully the next release will be able to let user add his/her own components from own written classes.